# why the response is strange in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I use postman to test 
http://192.168.1.208:8090/jobsappName=sparkJoin001&classPath=com.mymoon.sql.SparkJoin
It's ok! It returns the message:

```
{
  "status": "STARTED",
  "result": {
    "jobId": "3a47f931-f040-4e4a-a688-331f1918ae82",
    "context": "6a171d9d-com.mymoon.sql.SparkJoin"
  }
}
```

> it's http status is 202!

I config in the wso2 esb and return some messages, but the browse shows the mixed message! It's stange!

The config is :

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="d" context="/dd">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/submit">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="text">
            <format>{"uuid":"201456541","table": "aa/aa_table","condition":"names|91194185"}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="POST" uri-template="http://192.168.1.208:8090/jobs?appName=CU&amp;classPath=com.mymoon.ses.SparkCount"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="asdfsadf" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="text">
            <format>{"jobId":"$1", "table":"$2"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.result.jobId"/>
               <arg value="test"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

So I test   http://192.168.1.101:8280/dd/submit . The browser  shows such message.

```
{
  "status": "STARTED",
  "result": {
    "jobId": "548e9590-e442-439f-9234-223bf5bf669e",
    "context": "dd803c98-com.mymoon.ses.SparkCount"
  }
}{"jobId":"548e9590-e442-439f-9234-223bf5bf669e", "table":"test"}
```

I hope message is this:

```
{"jobId":"548e9590-e442-439f-9234-223bf5bf669e", "table":"test"}
```

So I'm confused! Help me!Thanks!

Comment: I tested your configuration on ESB 4.9.0 (backend: SoapUI), and it returns the correct response. What's the esb version you use? What do you see in the esb console?

Comment: I also use ESB 4.9.0. In general, it has no problem to test the other service. But I test the spark job's rest service, it has a problem. In the response of esb,  I don't use  $. to get the data and  It has no problem. If I use the $. to get the response data, it occur. So I doubt it is relate to the http status 202.

Comment: Another strange thing is that I use first $. to  get josn object, it's null. But the second is ok! So strange!!!!

Answer (score 0):

i have tested using ESB 4.8.0. i have modified your API code as follows. I tested with mock service and its working. only change i made is change media-type json from text

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="d" context="/dd">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/submit">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"></log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"uuid":"201456541",   "table": "aa/aa_table",   "condition":"names|91194185"   }</format>
            <args></args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http method="post" uri-template="http://demo2965385.mockable.io/test"></http>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="asdfsadf" expression="json-eval($.)"></property>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"jobId":"$1", "table":"$2"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.result.jobId"></arg>
               <arg value="test"></arg>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send></send>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

response look as follows

```
{
  "jobId": "3a47f931-f040-4e4a-a688-331f1918ae82",
  "table": "test"
}
```

Comment: Text and json are both ok! I think the difference is the endpoint. My back-end service returns the 202 status. I think this is a problem.  But I can get the correct result from the browser directly. So I think there may be a problem in the esb.

Comment: No 202 is not a problem. i have tested with 202 also. but since you trying to send REST call with SEND mediator better to use following property `<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>` **if you are behind proxy this is really importent**

Comment: I test the property and it's not useful. It has no proxy. I add the js script in the response.*<script language="js">payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();var total = payload.result.jobId;mc.setPayloadJSON({"total":total});</script>*. I find the payload is null.

Comment: problem is we cant reproduce your issue. its working fine for me. if you can share your complete API code + response which sent by back end. so i can mock your service and fix your code if any.